# how to compare the file names that are inside a folder (Datalake) using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have list of files inside a datalake folder and I have list of files names stored in the .CSV File..

My requirement is to compare the files names in the Datalake folder with the filenames in the .CSV File and if the filenames are matching then I want to copy these files and if filenames are not matching then I want to send an Email with missing files in the datalake.

I have used GetMetaData  activity(child items) to get the list of files in the datalake folder and I'm stuck here. Now I want to compare these filenames with the filenames stored in the .CSV File and do the further operations.

Kindly Help

My requirement is to compare the files names in the Datalake folder with the filenames in the .CSV File and if the filenames are matching then I want to copy these files and if filenames are not matching then I want to send an Email with missing files in the datalake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get Metadata activity is taken, and dataset is created for datalake. ChildItems is taken as argument for output.

[image]

- Output of the metadata activity is passed in for each activity.
  `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

- Inside for-each, lookup is taken and csv file which contains list of file names is referred.

[image]

- If condition is taken and expression is given as
  `@contains(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),item().name)`
- In true case, copy activity is added to copy the matched file name into SQL database.

**Edited**- To copy from one location to other location in datalake, follow below steps 1 and 2

1. Source dataset is taken and in file path , file name is given as `@{item().name}`
   [image]

[image]

2. In Sink dataset also, file path is given similarly. This will dynamically create filename as in source.
   [image]

- In false case, append variable is added and all the values which do not match with lookup, got appended to variable of type **array**.

[image]

- Refer the **MS document** on [How to send email - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email) for sending email.

Comment: Thank you very much Aswin for your solution..

Comment: In true case,  How to copy only files which are matching to the another Datalake location ?

Comment: Check the answer. I have edited it for copying from one lacation to another location in datalake.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, The solution is working fine.

Comment: Also in False condition, Is there way to store all the values of append variable or( False condition values)  in a csv file in the data lake ?, I mean the file names which are not matching in a separate csv file

Comment: Post this as a new question in stack overflow to copy the data from variable to csv file. So that other community members will get helped on this.

Comment: Posted this question , Here's the link   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471581/how-to-copy-the-data-from-append-variable-activity-to-a-csv-file-using-azure-dat

Comment: Hi Aswin, can we store the false condition values directly in a csv file instead of storing in append variable or set variables ?