# How to copy the data from Append variable activity to a csv file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

How to copy the data from append variable activity to a csv file using Azure Data Factory

I have array of file names stored in append variable activity. I want to store all these files names inside a .CSV file in the data lake location.

For more info refer this
[how to compare the file names that are inside a folder (Datalake) using ADF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432836/how-to-compare-the-file-names-that-are-inside-a-folder-datalake-using-adf)

Comment: Do you want to add the value of the variable in the csv file? or create a new csv file

Comment: I want to create a new CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In this repro, Variable V1 (array type) is taken with values as in below image.

[image]

- New variable v2 of string type is taken and value is given as `@join(variables('V1'),decodeUriComponent('%0A'))`
  This step is done to join all the strings of the array using `\n (line feed)`.
  [image]
- Then Copy activity is taken and dummy source dataset with one row is taken.
  [image]
- In Source, **+New**  is selected and value is given as dynamic content `@varaiables('v2')`.

[image]

- Sink dataset is created for CSV file.
- In Mapping, import schemas is clicked and other than `col1` , all other columns are deleted.

[image]

- Then pipeline is debugged, and values got loaded in csv file.
  [image]

**Edited**

- Variable v2 is storing all the missing file names. (False activity of IF condition)
- After for-each, Set variable is added and variable **v3** (string type) is set as
  `@join(variables('v2'),decodeUriComponent('%0A'))`

[image]

- Then, in  copy activity, +New column is added in source
  [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249756/discussion-on-answer-by-aswin-how-to-copy-the-data-from-append-variable-activity).